# Defining a percentage width for a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to define a percentage width (70%) for a LinearLayout that contains some buttons, so that I can center it and so that the child buttons can fill_parent. Here's a picture showing what I mean:

[image: example]

My current layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/barContainer" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="40dp" android:background="@drawable/titlebackground">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/barLogo" android:src="@drawable/titlelogo"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="25dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:paddingLeft="5dp"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/searchTip" android:text="@string/searchTip"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp"></TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout im referring to has the id: linearLayout1. How do I do this?

Comment: Kudos for the excellent diagram that the higher ranking questions lack.

Comment: Anyone looking fro demo for doing this http://goo.gl/s9mp2W

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You have to set the weight property of your elements. Create three RelativeLayouts as children to your LinearLayout and set weights 0.15, 0.70, 0.15. Then add your buttons to the second RelativeLayout(the one with weight 0.70).

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">
        
        <!-- This is the part that's 70% of the total width. I'm inserting a LinearLayout and buttons.-->   
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                
                <Button 
                    android:text="Button1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:text="Button2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:text="Button3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </Button>
                
            </LinearLayout>
        <!-- 70% Width End-->
        
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why are the weights 0.15, 0.7 and 0.15? Because the total weight is 1 and 0.7 is 70% of the total.

**Result:**

[image]

Edit: Thanks to @SimonVeloper for pointing out that the orientation should be horizontal and not vertical and to @Andrew for pointing out that weights can be decimals instead of integers.

Comment: That's very hackish but also quite clever, thank you!

Comment: The buttons now stack upon eachother(showing only one button), how do I set the orientation in the relativeLayout like in a LinearLayout?

Comment: On the first button, use android:layout_alignParentTop="true" and then android:layout_marginTop="50dp". Then on the second button you do android:layout_below="@+id/firstbutton". And so on.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out myself.

Comment: You can set weights using decimals: 0.15, 0.7, 0.15

Comment: shouldn't the weight be referred to the height in case of vertical orientation and to the width in case of horizontal orientation?

Comment: you can replace the other 2 invisible Relative Layout to View, and set layout_width/height to 0dp, and visibility to invisible. Might be less costly.

Answer (score 42):

i know another solution, that work with weight:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              android:weightSum="10" 
              android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="7">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have no idea why it's rated so low, i guess this is much better solution than the accepted one!

Comment: @deathangel908 Agree! and so much cleaner!

Comment: It is clean, but it doesn't work for me: the inner LinearLayout takes up the whole width of the screen (at least in Layout Editor preview). Did you mean for the inner LinearLayout to have `android:layout_width="0dp"`? That's what the documentation indicates (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight), and it works for me in Layout Editor preview.

Comment: This is a cleaner solution. However, in nested layout instead of `layout_width="wrap_content"` it should be `layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: Simple and good solution

Answer (score 29):

Hope this can help

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_dummy1" android:layout_weight=".15">
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight=".7">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_dummy2" android:layout_weight=".15">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

(1) Set layout_width to "0dip"
(2) Set the layout_height to .xx (% you want)

Comment: Àfter reading and trying a lot of different options I am pretty convinced this is the best answer. P.S. Android layouts suck big time! Cannot believe they don't accept relative (%) values! thanks for this answer.

Comment: Are you sure about setting layout_height (2)?

Comment: lifesaver. Works with C# Xamarin axml layout.

Comment: Bingo!  This worked like a champ for me, and allowed me to stick with LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 7):

I think Emiam's approach is right. But also agree with Simon Veloper (one of commentators of Emiam's answer) : When we need the buttons in 70% of width, we should use horizontal orientation for Linearlayout and set width of each Relativelayout to 0dip and their weight as specified
So I suggest this version :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layoutContainer" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="14">

            //This is where you add buttons. You can make them "fill_parent".
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

As a latest update to android in 2015, Google has included percent support library

> com.android.support:percent:23.1.0

You can refer to this site for example of using it

> https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample

### Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
}
```

### In the layout:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ff44aacc"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="70%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/top_left"
        android:background="#ffe40000"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="30%" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_left"
        android:background="#ff00ff22"
        app:layout_heightPercent="80%" />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: link only answers are highly discouraged here.Please add link as reference only.

Answer (score 4):

Use new percentage support library

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.0.0'
```

See below example

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

For More Info
[Tutorial1](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en) [Tutorial2](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/percentrelativelayout-in-android/) [Tutorial3](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/)

Answer (score 3):

You can't define width/height/margins/... using percents in your XML. But what you would want to use is the "weight" attribute, which is, IMO, the most similar thing.

Another method would be to set the sizes programmatically after you inflate the layout in your code, by getting the size of your screen and calculating needed margins.

Comment: can I do this with ´height´ ?

Answer (score 3):

****You can use `layout_weight` properties. If you want to take 70% of parent width you must set child `layout_width` property value 0dp, like `android:layout_width="0dp"`****

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue applying some padding to the LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background"
    android:padding="35dip">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This probably won't give you an exact percentage but can be easily graduated and avoid extra unnecessary layout elements.

Answer (score 1):

Google introduced new API called [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Add compile dependency like

compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'

in that PercentRelativeLayout is what we can do percentagewise layout