# Specifying items in an android grid layout to re-size to fill screen height

Tags: java, android, xml, responsive, grid-layout

I have a `GridLayout` that has 6 elements (`TextView's`).

I set the `columnCount` to **3**.

The width of each element, `TextView`, is 33% as the `columnCount` is 3. This is exactly how I want it - however, the height of each element `TextView` does not fill to match the screen (50% height for both the first and second row of elements as there are two rows of 3 elements - a grid of 3x2).

This is the XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ddx.project_dnd.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tile1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tile2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tile3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tile4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tile5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tile6" />

    </GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As seen in the above XML, each of the element `TextView's` height is set to **100dp**. Is there a way using a GridLayout specifically, to expand each of the elements height to 50% via the XML layout? I've tried searching but find mostly answers akin to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574875/making-ui-elements-relative-to-screen-size) resource and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762987/creating-gridview-with-3-rows-of-imageviews-that-fill-the-whole-screen) which is programmatically, or am I suffering an XY problem with my choice of Layout?

Comment: Why not you use `android:layout_rowWeight` instead of setting height of `TextView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tile6" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect solution.