# Android ImageButton relative width

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'd like to ask about one of the hardest thing for me (as a programmer) in android. As I make software mostly without designer (to be honest - totally without a designer) I can't figure out the following:

When I draw a png I use px (not dp) as image width.

I drew a button image with the following sizes:
hdpi: 318x45 
mdpi: 212x30
(6 to 4 ratio)
and I would like my button be 80% width of Galaxy s2 which is

> Screen Size in Pixels: 480 Pixel x 800 Pixel Screen Size in dp: 352dp
>   x 587dp

But also I would like to have the same width (80%) for hdpi 10' tablet. Is it possible or I'm missing something?

And is it possible to make 80% but not more than XXX pixel width?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide different size images for different screen sizes and densities. When you think about it there's only a few different formats you need to worry about. You will then just create an "80%" size image for each of those formats, place them in the seperate drawable folders, and use them accordingly.

The [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on supporting multiplce screen size and [providing alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) are actually pretty comprehensive on how to do this.

Otherwise I'm sorry you don't have a designer. My tip - make your icons originally in Adobe Illustrator if you have it that way you can easily scale them to whatever size you need. As vector images they won't lose quality so you can change the size all you want. When you're ready, just export for web and devices at the size break points and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `android:layout_weight` attribute.

Details outlined in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557220/defining-a-percentage-width-for-a-linearlayout)