# Add Vertical and Horizontal Scrolling Programmatically to LinearLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout of a activity as follows:
[image]

the `game_board.xml` code is is follows:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layoutFilterContent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:background="#837E7C" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layoutTopicGrade"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="#BCC6CC" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layoutGames"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="#E5E4E2" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The `java` code in `GameBoardActivity.java` is as follows:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class GameBoardActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout topicGrade;
    LinearLayout gameContent;
    ScrollView scroll;
    ImageButton[] imgBtn;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "InlinedApi", "ResourceAsColor" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_board);

        topicGrade = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutTopicGrade);

        scroll = new ScrollView(this);
        scroll.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
        scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        scroll.addView(topicGrade);

        imgBtn = new ImageButton[15];

        for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
            imgBtn[i] = new ImageButton(this);
            imgBtn[i].setId(i);
            imgBtn[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            topicGrade.addView(imgBtn[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_board, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I'm getting `error` as: `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`
I first tried adding buttons to `LinearLayout1` without `ScrollView`, and I'm able to add the buttons as I want, but when I implement `ScrollView` I'm getting the error as mentioned above. So I got stuck and didn't try anything on `LinearLayout2`
 
Please anyone help me to design the activity shown above,

Comment: i added the xml you need to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what do you want do achiev? this is what you actually doing:

```
setContentView(R.layout.game_board);
```

->game_board is inflatet with both childs layoutTopicGrade and layoutGames

```
topicGrade = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutTopicGrade);
```

->this is a instance of layoutTopicGrade

```
scroll = new ScrollView(this);
```

->you create a scroll view

```
scroll.addView(topicGrade);
```

->you add topicGrade to the scroll view

**This failed, because topicGrade already has a parent (layoutFilterContent)**

```
this.setContentView(scroll);
```

->you set the croll view as content.
(why did you set R.layout.game_board as content before?)

if you only want topicGrade in a `ScrollView` as `ContentView`, why didn't you create a xml with this structure?

if it is recommended to do it like you do, the solution is:

```
topicGrade = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutTopicGrade);
((LinearLayout)topicGrade.getParent()).removeView(topicGrade)
```

but i can't see why you should do it in this way ^^

--edit:
now i've got it, here is the you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="4" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vertical_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. line `this.setContentView(scroll);` was added by mistake, I've removed this line. I want to divide the `activity` in 2 parts `(Say if 4 is total, then  1/4 and  3/4)` as I've mentioned in my question and you can see the Layout in the image I provided. How can I divide the layout to `1/4` with `Vertical Scroll` and `3/4` with `Horizontal Scroll`?

Answer (score 1):

Each element can have exactly one parent, that's an XML file structure.

In your layout xml file you defined `layoutTopicGrade` as the child of `layoutFilterContent`. Then, in the code, you set `layoutTopicGrade` as the child of the newly created `ScrollView`.

You should wrap your `layoutTopicGrade` the `ScrollView`. Also, since you're not doing any dynamic configuration to the `ScrollView`, there's no reason adding it in the code, you should do it straight in the layout xml file:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollViewTopicGrade"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layoutTopicGrade"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="#BCC6CC" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

**EDIT**

In order to have `layoutTopicGrade` take 25% of parent's width and `layoutGames` take 75%, do the following:

1. Move the `layout_weight` and `layout_width` from `layoutTopicGrade` to the `ScrollView`.
2. Set `ScrollView`'s `layout_weight` to `.25`.
3. Set `layoutGames`'s `layout_weight` to `.75`.
4. `layoutTopicGrade`'s children should have `layout_width` set to `fill_parent`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6557686/978502).

---

**ADDITION**

BTW, looks like the line `this.setContentView(scroll);` should be deleted. `Activity.setContentView` is used to set a view for the whole activity = whole screen. But your `ScrolView` is apparently only for the topic layout. Rather the whole game board is the activity's content view, as you use it a few lines of code earlier: `setContentView(R.layout.game_board);` (so keep that one).

Comment: Thank you for your response. line `this.setContentView(scroll);` was added by mistake, I've removed this line. As you told to use `<ScrollView>` directly to the `xml`. If I'll use `<ScrollView>` directly in `xml` which I've posted in the question, I'll not get the two side by side Layout.

Comment: @Sush19 Anyway you look at it, you can and should do it in the xml. Did you try moving the weight to the `ScrollView`?

Comment: @Sush19 (1) move the `layout_weight` and `layout_width` from `layoutTopicGrade` to the `ScrollView`. (2) set `ScrollView`'s `layout_weight` to `.25`. (3) set `layoutGames`'s `layout_weight` to `.75`. (4) `layoutTopicGrade`'s children should have `layout_width` set to `fill_parent`.