# How to set both width and height of layouts as percentages in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I need to create a `horizontal layout` as follows :[image: Layout Pic]

I can set the total width of the layout of C using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` but I'm completely stumped at setting the rest of the layouts. Any help is highly appreciated.
The whole app is set to run on a  horizontal layout only, if that helps in decide what method to set the layouts.

Comment: add image its not loading

Comment: By using weights (In a LinearLayout derivate (°) container), you can specify a percentage for 1 dimension at a time. You can nest 2 LinearLayouts (or derivates) to achieve a percentage scaling for both directions. But that's not good for performance. (°) Derivates of LinearLayout: LinearLayout, TableRow, RadioGroup, ...

Comment: try this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557220/defining-a-percentage-width-for-a-linearlayout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:weightSum="100" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="#FF0000" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="#00FF00" >
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:background="#FFFF00" >
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use LinearLayout's with a certain weight like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_C"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is correct too but the first answer is more complete as it shows exactly what I wanted with 3 layouts. My mistake in not making it clear that the 3 components (A,B & C) were all layouts.