# Making a LinearLayout take up to a percentage width of it's parent container

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to make a `LinearLayout` in Android take UP TO a percentage width of it's parent container?

In CSS it might look like:

`.elm { max-width:70%; }`

How would I achieve the same effect with `LinearLayout` and `Android`?

This isn't the same question as questions previously asked such as [Defining a percentage width for a LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557220/defining-a-percentage-width-for-a-linearlayout?rq=1) , because that makes it take up a percentage of the width, it doesn't define the max width as a percentage.

EDIT:

Tried @jungleboys suggestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bubble_outerWrapper"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"  >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bubble_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"  >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bubble_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="TextViewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww!"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This doesn't work, does anyone else have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bubble_outerWrapper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bubble_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="TextViewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww! TextViewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww! TextViewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww! TextViewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww! TextViewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww!"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```