# Layout using percents

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to layout the following: A title using the 20% of the screen, and a group of images using the rest (80%) in which each image uses the same amount of space. All this is vertically. This is the code I am using

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:orientation = "vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/dashboard_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:orientation = "vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" 
        android:layout_weight= "33" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_weight= "33"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_weight= "33" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is however what I am getting

[image]

Which is not the desired layout (notice the title has more than the 20% of the screen height). Also, I am getting some warnings about performance issues using nested layout_weight

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining a percentage width for a LinearLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557220/defining-a-percentage-width-for-a-linearlayout)

Comment: I have read that, but I didn't get it. Do I need two `relativeLayout`, one for the title an other for the images?

Comment: Yes. But, it can be any layout.

Comment: yes.. you need two layouts

Comment: See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Comment: @VenomVendor But then I don't get why it doesnt work. I am already using two layouts

Comment: when you use `layout_weight` based on orientation `layout_height` or `layout_width` should be set to `0dp` If you have a screen shot of how it should look, kindly update the question.

Comment: @VenomVendor Thanks, that was indeed the problem as I just reported =)

Comment: @VenomVendor In fact, as this is just a silly question I answered myself, if you don't mind I will delete this thread.

Comment: Yes, please. That's really great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed just by setting

> android:layout_height="0px"