# Android layouts: create board, centered and automatic sized

Tags: android

I spent a week trying to make this, but with no result.

I want to make something like what's in the image.

1. I want to make table of buttons (the user chooses 5x5, 10x10, or
   something else)
2. The table should be centered horizontally and vertically
3. Each button in the table cell should be sized relatively to the
   device screen
4. Each button should be a rectangle.

   [image]

EDIT:
Here my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private int game_counter=1;
        private int nof_columns = 10;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            GridView table_layout = new GridView(this);
            table_layout.setNumColumns(this.nof_columns);


            int button_size=5;

            for(int rows=1; rows<=this.nof_columns; rows++) {
                TableRow rowT = new TableRow(this);

                for(int columns=1; columns<=this.nof_columns; columns++){
                    Button bn = new Button(this);
                    bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            onclick_function(v);
                        }
                    });
                    bn.setId(100 + rows * this.nof_columns + columns);
                    bn.setWidth(button_size);
                    bn.setHeight(button_size);


                    bn.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    MyTags tag = new MyTags();
                    bn.setTag(tag);
                    rowT.addView(bn);
                }
                //rowT.setPadding(-5,-5,-5,-5);

                rowT.setMinimumHeight(button_size);
                rowT.setMinimumWidth(button_size);

                table_layout.addView(rowT);
                //table_layout.setPadding(-70,-70,-70,-70);
            }
            setContentView(table_layout);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code and be more specific with your issue. What doesn't work at the moment? Please have a read on how to ask a good question to increase chances of solving your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello PiotrWolkowski, thanks a lot for your comment.
I'm providing my code, but I don't really understand what the reason for that?
I don't ask for writing code for me, I'm asking for help with an ideas and ways how to achieve my goal.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
It's mentioned in [Defining a percentage width for a LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557220/defining-a-percentage-width-for-a-linearlayout)

Later I'll post here my code with the board.

Thanks!