# Adjust the width of a single Linear Layout child element that are currently equal in width?

Tags: android, xml

I have three TextViews of equal width and height as you can see here:

[image]

You can see there is more text in the third element that fits okay at the moment. During the running of the app when the percentage is populated it results in the third child element taking a new line in order to fit all the text in the element like so:

[image]

The text in the second child element is never going to fill up all the space that it has spare.

How do I adjust the width of the second child element slightly so I can give more room to the third element so that the text always fits.

I've tried MaxWidth - This didn't change anything.

I changed this width to even 1dp but this didn't change anything noticeable.

I tried MaxLines this worked and kept the element on one line but the percentage over shot the screen and disappeared like so:

[image]

I've thought about auto-scaling the test so it always fits but this seems over-kill for what I want & the text is already small enough as it is.

I did want all the elements to be equal in size at the beginning but since I can't fit the necessary text in the third element I think the best way would be to slightly use some of the room that the second element isn't using. Is there better ways?

What's the best way to go about this?

Here's my current XML code:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_infoMiddleRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear_infoBottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_FooBar"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/tv_MatchAVG" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Test"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/tv_140plus"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_doublesPercentage"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/tv_doubles" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find another question that was having the same problem.

To solve it I needed to change the weight of each child element.

The first and second I changed to 0.30.

The third to 0.40 adding up to the weight that was originally 1.

[Here's the answer in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557220/defining-a-percentage-width-for-a-linearlayout/40263796)